# Map IDs to matrix rows in Hadoop/MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, matrix, mapreduce, uniqueidentifier, unique-index

I have data about users buying products. I want to create a binary matrix of size `|users|` x `|products|` such that the element `(i,j)` in the matrix is 1 iff `user_i` has bought `product_j`, else the value is 0.

Now, my data looks something like

```
userA, productX
userB, productY
userA, productZ
...
```

UserIds and productIds are all strings. My problem is, how to map these IDs to row indices (for users) and column indices (for products) in the matrix.

There are over a million unique userIds and roughly 3 million productIds.

To make the problem well defined: given the `user1, product1` like input above, how do I convert it to something like

```
1,1
2,2
1,3
```

where `userA` is mapped to row 0 of the matrix, `userB` is mapped to row 1, `productX` is mapped to column 0 and so on.

Given the size of data, I would have to use Hadoop Map-Reduce but can't think of a foolproof way of efficiently doing this.

This can be solved if we can do the following:

1. Dump unique userIds.
2. Dump unique productIds.
3. Map each unique userId in (1) to a row index.
4. Map each unique productId in (2) to a column index.

I can do (1) and (2) easily but having trouble coming up with an efficient approach to solve (3) (4 will be solved if we solve 3).

I have a couple of solutions but they are not foolproof.

**Solution 1 (naive) for step 3 above**

- Map all userIds and emit the same key (say "1") for all map tasks.
- Have a `long` counter initialized to 0 in `setup()` of the reducer.
- In the `reduce()`, emit the counter value along with the input userId and increment the counter by 1.

This would be very inefficient since all 100 million userIds would be processed by a single reducer.

**Solution 2 for step 3 above**

- While mapping userIds, emit each userId against a key which is an integer uniformly sampled from 1,2,3....N (where N is configurable. N = 100 for example). In a way, we are partitioning the input set.
- Within the mapper, use Hadoop counters to count the number of userIds assigned to each of those random partitions.
- In the reducer setup, first access the counters in the mapping stage to determine how many IDs were assigned to each partition. Use these counters to determine the `start` and `end` values for that partition.
- Iterate (while counting) over each userId in `reduce` and generate matrix rowId as `start_of_partition` + `counter`.
- context.write(userId, matrix row Id)

This method should work but I am not sure how to handle cases when reducer tasks failed/killed.

I believe there should be ways of doing this which I am not aware of. Can we use hashing/modulo to achieve this? How would we handle collisions at scale?

Comment: `first access the counters in the mapping stage` this won't work sadly. I recommend using spark in this case and use `zipWithIndex()`, it makes the whole task basically 3-4 lines of code.

Comment: In case you're curious how it works. It counts over all partitions in parallel and then on the next stage it is just using the lengths per partition to generate the index offsets per partition and increment per row. That's equivalent of having two map only jobs where you transfer the index information via configs or hdfs files. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/ZippedWithIndexRDD.scala

Comment: `zipwithIndex` seems like the solution. I am, however, not sure how to replace `userA, productX` with `1,1`. How would `zipWithIndex` replace the product IDs? Do you have some sample code?

Comment: You need to join the product names and the zipWithIndex result on the product name itself, that gives you the index in that column.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasJungblut.